# Code only works fine for 2 steps and the output begins to deviate after 2 steps

Tags: java, chess

I have made a program to check the number of positions a king can move in K steps. I have a chessboard of size 8×8 with rows and columns marked from 1 to 8. Suppose our king is at position 1,3; he can move to 5 new places and may remain to the current position, so overall our king can move to 6 places. The validity of the new place where our king can move can be checked by the formula `Square(r'-r)+Square(c'-c)<=2` where `r'` and `c'` are the positions of cells to be checked.

My code works fine for K= 1 and 2, however the results begin to deviate for 3 or more values of K.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Chess {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases;
        testCases = input.nextInt();
        while (testCases-- > 0 && testCases <= 512) {
            int R, C, K, count = 0;
            R = input.nextInt();
            C = input.nextInt();
            K = input.nextInt();
            if (R >= 1 && R <= 8 && C <= 8 && C >= 1 && K <= 8 && K >= 1) {
                for (double rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= 8; rowIndex++) {
                    for (double columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= 8; columnIndex++) {
                        if (Math.pow((rowIndex - R), 2) + Math.pow((columnIndex - C), 2) <= (2 * Math.pow(K, 2))) {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you could come up with a minimal test case that shows the problem, including a comment about why the test behavior is wrong.

Comment: Try to isolate the few lines that are misbehaving, and post only those. Supply some test data, what your code currently does and what you want it to do. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure, but you do know that you technically start R,C, and K at 1, while count remains at 0, right? This is because you move to the next int, before working with them.

I would adjust the code to as follow, and see if that yields better results!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Chess {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases;
        testCases = input.nextInt();
        while (testCases-- > 0 && testCases <= 512) {
            int R, C, K, count = 0;
            if (R >= 1 && R <= 8 && C <= 8 && C >= 1 && K <= 8 && K >= 1) {
                for (double rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= 8; rowIndex++) {
                    for (double columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= 8; columnIndex++) {
                        if (Math.pow((rowIndex - R), 2) + Math.pow((columnIndex - C), 2) <= (2 * Math.pow(K, 2))) {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            R = input.nextInt();
            C = input.nextInt();
            K = input.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for checking the validity of the new square is incorrect; it shouldn't involve squaring. As you discovered, for `K = 3`, your condition becomes

```
(r' - r)² + (c' - c)² ≤ 2 × 3² = 18
```

, which can, in fact, be satisfied by making `r' = r + 4` and `c' = c`, since 16 ≤ 18. But that implies the king moved four squares up!

Rather, you could restate your condition in each direction:

- The king can move `k` steps up, but no more than the 8<sup>th</sup> row, so the topmost row the king can reach is `rmax = min(r + k, 8)`;
- Similarly, `rmin = max(r - k, 1)`;
- Similarly, `cmax = min(c + k, 8)`;
- Similarly, `cmin = max(c - k, 1)`.

You can then simply compute the answer as `(rmax - rmin + 1) × (cmax - cmin + 1)`. This makes sense intuitively because the valid area should be a rectangle spanning rows `rmin` to `rmax` and columns `cmin` to `cmax`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, that's a very solution of my problem